# translate Swift to Objective-C automatically

Tags: objective-c, swift

may swift code translate to OC code automatically?

I wrote an app with swift, but as some reason need to translate to OC code, do anyone have solution?

Answer (score 3):

There is no automatic converter from Swift to Objective-C. Some Swift constructs cannot be represented directly in Objective-C. You will need to rewrite the code by hand in Objective-C.